# Problema al mostrar codigo qr en codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, php7

Buenas tengo un problema estoy trabajando con codeigniter 4 y php 7 mi problema es que intento generar un codigo qr pasandole como parámetro una clave encriptada en md5 el cual debería de generarme un codigo qr

```
use App\Libraries\ciqrcode; 
  header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
  $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $id=md5($hoy); 
  $qr=$this->ciqrcode->generate($id);
  return($qr);
```

pero al correr la aplicación me sale el siguiente error y no encuentro como solucionarlo, intente incluso usar otra libreria la de infiqr pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

```
"Undefined property: App\\Controllers\\Api_sistem::$ciqrcode",
```

y me estoy guiando del ejemplo de github

Comment: En que momento declaras $this->ciqrcode?, no veo la variable en la clase ni nada.En el codeigniter 3 lo cargabas con `$this->load->library('ciqrcode');` y lo podías llamar como tú lo haces, pero no funciona en el 4 de la misma manera.

Comment: precisamente estoy recién empezando a utilizar el 4 porque antes utilizaba el 3 y tenia dificultades para cargar la libreria